# Mostrar pagina html a traves de index.php > funcion.php

Tags: php, html

Me explico porque el titulo tal vez iba a ser un poco largo y he querido simplificarlo.

Tengo una pagina **index.php**, tiene una tabla, donde en un `tr`,`td` (`height` y `width` ya establecidos) tiene un `include ('/funciones/cargar_entrada.php')`, así que el contenido de este include se mostrará en est `tr`,`td`.

La funcion **cargar_entrada.php**, se conecta a una BBDD y recupera la ultima entrada (Ejemplo: **entrada1.html**). He intento que muestre `entrada1.html` probando con;

1. include
2. `echo "< a href='/../entradas/entrada1.html'>< /a>";`
3. `<script type="text/javascript">
        location.href='/../entradas/entrada1.html';
    </script>`

Hasta aquí todo está bien. El caso es que no muestra el contenido de `entrada.1html` en `cargar_entrada.php`...

[image: Os dejo una imagen para que me entendáis mejor por si os he liado]

Codigo de cargar_entrada.php

> $servidor=""; $usuario=""; $pass=""; $bbdd="";
>
> $conexion=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$pass,$bbdd) or die
>   ("Error 505 NOT FOUND");
>
> $sql="SELECT * FROM entradas ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
>   $tabla=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
>
> while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_object($tabla))   { $id=$fila->id; }
>
> header('Location:../entradas/entrada'.$id.'.html');

Se que es muy basico pero me funciona correctamente

Edito: Al final he optado por lo siguiente.

En index.php he creado un iframe con src=cargar_entrada.php, y este con el codigo que he puesto mas arriba, carga la ultima entrada correctamente.

Tema solucionado, gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Por favor comparte el código relevante de index.php y cargar_entrada.php

Comment: El codigo de cargar_entrada.php funciona bien, lo he probado directamente sin tener que cargarlo desde index.php y me muestra entrada1.html.

El codigo de index.php tambien es correcto, simplemente una tabla, con algunos tr, con td como dije mas arriba..

La cosa es mostrar entrada. en cargar_entrada.php y que a su vez esta lo muestra en index.php. Haciendolo desde cargar_entrada.php se muestra perfectamente, pero a la hora de hacerlo desde index.php no da resulta y muestra el siguiente error;

Comment: Sin conocer tu proyecto ni la forma como lo diseñaste es un poco difícil darte una solución a menos que agregues un poco de código. Puedes agregar el código editando la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dices que has intentado de tres formas distintas mostrar el contenido de un documento `html` dentro de una celda (`<td></td>`) de una tabla.

Bien, tu  primer intento fue usando "**include**":

Comentarte que estás haciendo lo correcto, pero debes saber que la directiva "include" se limita a "incluir" el contenido del archivo que le indiques. Comentas que:

> "La funcion cargar_entrada.php, se conecta a una BBDD y recupera la
>   ultima entrada (Ejemplo: entrada1.html)."

Entiendo que te refieres a que tienes un archivo "`cargar_entrada.php`" en el que tienes una función llamada "`cargar_entrada()`" que hace una consulta a una BBDD y recupera el nombre del archivo en el que está el código `html` de la última entrada. Comentarte que no sólo debes declarar y definir la función "`cargar_entrada()`" de ésta manera:

```
function cargar_entrada()
{
    // Consulta a BBDD y retorno del nombre del archivo con la última entrda
    return $ruta_archivo;
}
```

Si no que tienes que **invocarlo** en algún sitio o bien en el propio archivo cargar_entrada.php:

```
function cargar_entrada()
{
    // Consulta a BBDD y retorno del nombre del archivo con la última entrda
    return $ruta_archivo;
}

//Invocar la función y vuelcas el contenido del archivo devuelto
echo file_get_content(cargar_entrada());
```

o bien tras el include:

```
<td>
<?
include("cargar_entrada.php");
echo file_get_content(cargar_entrada());
?>
</td>
```

De cualquiera de las dos formas se mostraría correctamente el contenido del archivo `enrada1.html` dentro de la celda.

Advertencias:
* antes de mostrar, comprueba la existencia del archivo

He supuesto muchas cosas, espero haber acertado. Si he acertado muestrános el código de cargar_pagina.php y como lo invocas dentro de td.

Comment: Actualizado el mensaje principal con el codigo.